# Unexpected result with grouped AutoSuggestBox on mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm using an `AutoSuggestBox` with grouping support using the style found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a3a0e15-6209-41ff-b347-2280dca19738/uwpxaml-autosuggestbox-and-groupstyle?forum=wpdevelop), but I'm having a weird issue in how the suggestion popup is shown on mobile (on desktop is 100% fine, I can see the grouped list inside the popup).

What happens is that, while I'm writing in the `AutoSuggestBox`, an ungrouped popup with wrong positioning is shown, as you can see here:

[image: mobile1]

This lasts until I select one of the items, but the selection provides even weirder results by showing the correct popup, even if it's filtered with the text that I had before selecting the item.

[image: mobile2]

You can see the correct behavior on desktop here:

[image: desktop]

```
<AutoSuggestBox Style="{StaticResource GroupedAutoSuggestBoxStyle}"
                UpdateTextOnSelect="True"                            
                TextMemberPath="Name"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ServicesCollectionViewSource.View, Mode=OneWay}"
                TextChanged="ServicesFilterAutoSuggestBox_OnTextChanged"
                QuerySubmitted="ServicesFilterAutoSuggestBox_OnQuerySubmitted"
                LostFocus="ServicesFilterAutoSuggestBox_OnLostFocus"
                AutoMaximizeSuggestionArea="True"                            
                Grid.Column="1">

...

private void ServicesFilterAutoSuggestBox_OnTextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Reason != AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput) return;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender.Text) && ViewModel.AccountService != null)
    {
        // User canceled previous selection, so we reset it
        ViewModel.AccountService = null;
    }
    // Filter the results
    ServicesCollectionViewSource.Source = from services
        in ViewModel.Services
        where services.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(sender.Text.ToLowerInvariant())
        group services by services.Section.Id;
}


private void ServicesFilterAutoSuggestBox_OnQuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
    {
        ViewModel.AccountService = (Service) args.ChosenSuggestion;
    }
    else
    {        
        ViewModel.AccountService = null;        
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this works fine on desktop while it has this weird behavior on mobile, and I really need your help.

Comment: I agree with the `GroupedAutoSuggestBoxStyleyou` adopt is correct. 
From my opinion, there is no bug in your code. Could you show more detail about your target device version?

Comment: Min version: 10586, Target version: 14393. Having this problem on both 14393 emulator and my Lumia 950 (14393.693). Please let me know if you need more details or any other information.

Comment: Could I touch your project? I would like to verify this issue on the real device.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT here's a [link](https://github.com/Gh0s7/AutoSuggestBoxRepro) to a repro project. What I've noticed is that the wrong popup is shown only if there's enough space on top, that's why I added two `AutoSuggestBox`. The one on top works almost fine (messed selection logic when copying from my project), the other one shows the wrong popup.